# How to disable sftp subsystem for a specific user or group?

Tags: ssh, sftp

On a linux server running **OpenSSH**,

How can I **disable sftp access** (the sftp subsystem) **for a specific user/group?**

The user should only be able to access a shell but have no sftp access.

**Edit:**

The purpose is to give users a ssh key which can only be used to execute one specific command (using the command="..." option in authorized_keys). And they shouldn't be allowed to use sftp.
Is it already taken care of when using the command="..." option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the SFTP SubSystem where it spawns a separate process, you could create a sftp group and only allow execution of the `sftp-server` binary for that group.  It will not be possible to do this with the newer internalized sftp daemon, which is specified with `internal-sftp`.

If they have shell access, they will still be able to scp.  Do you have a particular goal in mind?

**Edit**

If you want to restrict your user to only executing or utilizing a specific program, I would probably recommend a shell wrapper instead.  `command=` might work but it seems more likely to be fallible.  I would do more testing to be sure.

A shell wrapper, such as [scponly](http://sublimation.org/scponly/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), will only allow the end-user to scp.  I have modified the source of scponly before to only allow CVS execution, for example.  This can also be done with a shell script but it is easier to make mistakes if you do not fully understand the scope of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to give a ssh key to users which they can only use for a specific command (with the command="..." option in authorized_keys). See my edit.