# Fatal: unable to initialise SFTP: could not connect

Tags: sftp, cygwin, cygwin-sshd

I'm running OpenSSH on Cygwin, which I'm trying to use as an SFTP server only. I installed it first with just the default settings (external SFTP server `sftp-server`) and it worked. I was able to run PuTTY's PSFTP and "open localhost" and browse my files.

However for security I wanted to:

- Only allow SFTP access (not SSH)
- Only allow me to login (not other users)
- Only allow me to browse my own home directory
- Only allow read-only access

To achieve this I put the following at the end of `/etc/sshd_config`:

```
Subsystem   sftp    internal-sftp

Match User myusername
        ChrootDirectory /home/myusername
        AllowTCPForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp -d / -R

Match User !myusername
        ForceCommand echo 'successful login man, congrats'
```

(The last part is from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/817486/444339), which essentially prevents the matching user from logging in.)

Note that I also added `-d /` to the `internal-sftp` command-line, as it told me it defaults to the home directory, so I thought it might try to load `/home/myusername` by default, which would map to `/home/myusername/home/myusername` on the real system (a path that does not exist).

However when trying to login, I now get the following error:

```
psftp> open localhost
login as: myusername
myusername@localhost's password:
Fatal: unable to initialise SFTP: could not connect
psftp>
```

Interestingly though, I am on the server, just not actually on the SFTP:

```
psftp> open localhost
login as: myusername
myusername@localhost's password:
Fatal: unable to initialise SFTP: could not connect
psftp> open localhost
psftp: already connected
psftp> pwd
Remote directory is (null)
psftp>
```

What am I doing wrong, or how can I get logs for further troubleshooting?

Comment: Run another instance of sshd with ```/usr/sbin/sshd -D -d -p 2222``` and try to connect, check the debug output

Answer (score 1):

From sshd manual:

```
ChrootDirectory
Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after 
authentication. All components of the pathname must be root-owned 
directories that are not writable by any other user or group. After the 
chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home directory.
```

Most likely your home directory is not owned by root and sshd is refusing to chroot to a non-root owned directory, as it's unsafe.
Create /home/chroot, chown it to root and move your home directory under that.

To easily debug these problems and avoid locking yourself out, I recommend running a separate instance of sshd on a different port, in no-detach mode and with debug enabled:

```
 /usr/sbin/sshd -D -d -p 2222
```